# Union in Struct Error

Tags: c, struct, unions

I have the following struct:

```
struct type1 {
    struct type2 *node;
    union element {
        struct type3 *e;
        int val;
    };
};
```

When initialising a pointer `*f` that points to an instance of `type1` and doing something like:
`f.element->e` or even just `f.element`, I get:

```
error: request for member ‘element’ in something not a structure or union
```

What am I overseeing here?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `f`? Maybe you mean `f->element.e`?

Comment: `element` is the union tag, not a member name. Try with `struct { ... union element { ... } elem; };` and `f.elem`.

Comment: @DanielFischer that just gives the union a different name than its type. Why would it work? I define my struct without adding anything between the } and ; at the end and it works fine.

Comment: @Darksky Your `struct` member needs a name to access it. The name is given after the type. `struct type1 { ... ; union { ... } element; };` would create a member `element` with type (untagged) `union {...}`.

Comment: @Darksky: In C 1999 and earlier, adding a name to the end of the union declaration does not just give it a different name than its type. It gives it a name. Without that, it does not have a name; there is no object, no member in the enclosing struct. Without that, it is just a declaration of a type, not of a member.

Comment: @DanielFischer: C 2011 introduced anonymous unions and structures, in which case the union does not need a name.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True (although, s/does not need/must not have/). But C2011 is not yet widely supported, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element` is the name of the union, not the name of a member of `type1`. You must give `union element` a name:

```
struct type1 {
struct type2 *node;
    union element {
        struct type3 *e;
        int val;
    } x;
};
```

then you can access it as:

```
struct type1 *f;
f->x.e
```

Comment: Maybe you should malloc memory for your `f`?

Comment: `f` must be initialized somehow, yes.

Comment: There may be some issue of C versions here. C 2011 introduced anonymous structures and unions, in which case `f->e` would work with the original declaration. However, if Darksky is using an earlier version of C, then the union declaration must be modified as shown in this answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Correct, but even then, one wouldn't say: `f->element.e`

Comment: f is already initialised in `malloc`. This solves it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If f is a pointer, then you may access "element" using f->element, or (*f).element

Update: just saw that "element" is the union name, not a member of the struct.
You may try

```
union element {
    struct type3 *e;
    int val;
} element;
```

So the final struct would be like this:

```
struct type1 {
    struct type2 *node;
    union element {
        struct type3 *e;
        int val;
    } element;
};
```

And now you can access element members like this, through a type1 *f:

```
struct type1 *f;

// assign f somewhere

f->element.val;
```

Comment: Read the question please. That's what I did and that's the error I am getting.

Comment: @Darksky No. You did `f.element` and **not** `f->element` acording to your question.

Comment: No I **did** do both. Quoting: `f.element->e or even just f.element, I get`.

Comment: @Darksky `f.element->e` or `f.element` is not the same as `f->element`. `f.` will always be an error with a pointer `*f` (but anyway the problem with the union still was there before the edit). Regards