# How can i declare a variable of a struct which is in a union and this union is in another struct

Tags: c++, struct

Sample Code

```
struct A
{

 union
  {

    struct B
    {
     short a:1;
     short b:1;

    }; 

  };


 };
```

I want to declare a variable a variable of struct B. How can i do so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037832/union-in-struct-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard does not allow nested types in an anonymous `union`. Your code is not legal.

From the C++ Draft Standard N3337:

> **9.5 Unions**
>
> ...
>
> 5 A union of the form
>
> `union` *{ member-specification } ;*
>
> is called an anonymous union; it defines an unnamed object of unnamed type. The *member-specification* of an anonymous union shall only define non-static data members. [ *Note:* Nested types and functions cannot
>   be declared within an anonymous union. — *end note* ]

Comment: when i use union and struct(inner) as anonymous, then i am unable to define a variable... code shown below

    struct A
    {

     union
      {

        struct
        {
         short a:1;
         short b:1;

        }two; 

      }one;


     };

Comment: when i declare a variable of outer struct, i am able to access the inner variables of union as well as inner-struct.

Comment: i want to declare directly a variable of inner struct